# How does Liliana's Standard Bearer work if Kaervek the Spiteful is on the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say one creature has died this turn. I have [Kaervek, the Spiteful](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKaervek%2c%20the%20Spiteful%5d) on the battlefield, and then I flash in [Liliana's Standard Bearer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLiliana%27s%5d%2b%5bStandard%5d%2b%5bBearer%5d). This card has an enters-the-battlefield trigger which says "draw X cards where X is the number of creatures that died this turn".

Obviously the Standard Bearer is going to die immediately to Kaervek's static ability. When the enters-the-battlefield trigger resolves, does it count the Standard Bearer as a creature that died this turn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you will draw a card for the Standard Bearer as well. This is explained in the rulings under the card in Gatherer:

> The value of X is determined only as the triggered ability resolves. If Liliana’s Standard Bearer dies while that ability’s on the stack, it will count itself.

Comment: My God, I got to start reading the Gatherer rulings before asking questions.

Comment: @Allure I kinda think there should be stickied question and answer pointing out that if you have a MtG question, and you link to a card in your question, you should check whether there is an answer to your question at the bottom of the linked page.

Comment: @Acccumulation good idea, [I've proposed something that uses an existing Stack Exchange feature](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1989/12315).